# Is this snippet compiling? I don't think so Java 14 records

Tags: java, java-14, java-record

The weekend I was reading some about Java 14 preview feature records. I didn't want to make this question because seems to be a code for Brian Goetz, and we all know who this guy is and what represents to the Java ecosystem, but this was kicking in my head since and I know it will be learning for me.

The link is here. https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-14-feature-spotlight/?utm_campaign=infoq_content&utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=feed&utm_term=Java

Is something like this.

```
record PlayerScore(Player player, Score score) {
    // convenience constructor for use by Stream::map
    PlayerScore(Player player) { this(player, getScore(player)); }
}

List<Player> topN
    = players.stream()
             .map(PlayerScore::new)
             .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(PlayerScore::score))
             .limit(N)
             .map(PlayerScore::player)
             .collect(toList());
```

I assume that this line is returning a Score reference.

```
getScore(player)
```

Perhaps you have see it before I understand what it tries to do but there is something I don't understand. Maybe I'm wrong.

This line

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(PlayerScore::score))
```

The API for `comparingInt` is like this.

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor) {
```

But as long as I understand the method reference

```
PlayerScore::score
```

Is returning a Score reference from the Records tuple right? is not a Integer or resulting in a Integer

Or this would make the code compile I think perhaps is a typing error.

```
record PlayerScore(Player player, int score) {
    // convenience constructor for use by Stream::map
    PlayerScore(Player player) { this(player, getScore(player)); }
}
```

On my understanding this code would not compile, as I stated before; maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: At the moment, I am having difficulty understanding what you are asking. It will help if you create a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and run ourselves. The code snippets you have here aren't executable as they are given.

Comment: yes i understand. What i mean is that this line will not compile.  .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(PlayerScore::score))

Comment: my guess: in some draft of the article, `PlayerScore.score` was defined to be of type `int` instead of `Score`, and when it got changed, the comparison-line got overlooked.

Comment: i think the same thing.

Comment: As I understand it, a record creates a bean compatible get-method for each field.  So, `Player::score` is an error because there is no `score()` method.  There is, however, a generated `getScore()` method, so you probably want `comparingInt(Player::getScore)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this might not compile could be because `Score` is a type and not an `Integer` value. What you would need to do for comparing the `Score` of `record PlayerScore` is to ensure two things -

1. Use `Comparator.comparing` while

   ```
   List<Player> topN  = players.stream()
        .map(PlayerScore::new)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PlayerScore::score)) //here
        .limit(N)
        .map(PlayerScore::player)
        .collect(toList());
   ```
2. Make sure Score implements `Comparable` such as :

   ```
   class Score implements Comparable<Score> {
       @Override
       public int compareTo(Score o) {
           return 0; // implementation
       }
   }
   ```

---

Sadly, I don't see an implementation of your `Score` class in the linked document either, which is where it's crucial to understand what exactly has the author(or editor) missed there. For example, a simple `record` definition change would make the existing code work :

```
record PlayerScore(Player player, Integer score) { 
    // convenience constructor for use by Stream::map
    PlayerScore(Player player) {
        this(player, getScore(player));
    }
}

List<Player> topN = players.stream()
        .map(PlayerScore::new)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(PlayerScore::score))
        .limit(N)
        .map(PlayerScore::player)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Just a glance at that section, since it's in continuity with the previous example, what matters to correlate is the return type of `getScore(Player player)`.

```
// notice the signature change
static int getScore(Player player) {
    return 0;
}
```